# Is there a way to format dates inline in a VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, formatting

In a .page file, I have the following:

```
<li>Created on: {!proposal.CreatedDate}</li>
```

which prints out something really ugly like `Created on: Thu Aug 22 01:00:35 GMT 2013`.

Is there a way to format the date inline for date only with something like this (I am totally making stuff up here):

```
<li>Created on: {!proposal.CreatedDate:mm/dd/yyyy}</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to output the date/time field as a text and format it

```
<apex:outputText value=" {0, date, MM/dd/yyyy}" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(proposal.CreatedDate))}">
    <apex:param value="{!proposal.CreatedDate}" />
</apex:outputText>
```